# Alternative to `#define` macro for function alias in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, fmt

`fmtlib` has a function like:

```
template <typename S, typename... Args, typename Char = char_t<S>>
inline std::basic_string<Char> format(const S& format_str, Args&&... args) {
  return internal::vformat(
      to_string_view(format_str),
      {internal::make_args_checked<Args...>(format_str, args...)});
}
```

I've defined a macro for my convenience like:

`#define FMT fmt::format`

I use it like:

`std::cout<<FMT("Name: {0}\n", "Joe");`

Is there an alternative to using macro for this in C++11, preferably one that doesn't hit performance?

Comment: using namespace fmt?

Comment: Prefer `using fmt::format`.

Comment: hmmmmm, could you provide a [mre] which makes demonstrating a solution for your problem easier?

Comment: Yes: don't use macros or other ways to give things short cryptic names. Use long descriptive names instead. Long names are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the same function with a shorter name (in your own code). This function is named `FMT()` and it passes its parameters to `fmt::format()`, which is the original function you want to call:

```
template <typename S, typename... Args, typename Char = fmt::char_t<S>>
inline std::basic_string<Char> FMT(const S& format_str, Args&&... args) {
  return fmt::format(format_str, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q31Mbo)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: Sorry, have to ask for that before upvoting, being not a fan of code-only answers... But with explanation I do intend to upvote, for the joy of having learned something (after being completely wrong in public.... ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce a symbol from namespace you can use `using`.

If you want to make an easier to type *alias* for a function, you can use `auto&` or `auto` or `auto&&` or `auto const&`.

Or you could use a *lamdba* wrapper.

Any of which are better choices than a function-like *macro*, in my opinion.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

namespace Happy {

void Joy();

void Joy() {
    cout << "Joy and pride!\n";
}

} // Happy

int main() {
    // Example of using.
    using Happy::Joy;
    Joy();

    // Example of aliasing.
    auto& pride = Happy::Joy;
    auto pride2 = Happy::Joy;
    auto&& pride3 = Happy::Joy;
    auto const& pride4 = &Happy::Joy;
    pride();
    pride2();
    pride3();
    pride4();

    // Example of wrapping in a lambda.
    auto lambda = []{ Happy::Joy(); };
    lambda();
}
```